# InputType="textCapSentences" is not working on Chromebook's tablet mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, chromebook, android-inputtype

I am testing application on **Chromebook(HP x360 G13)**.

Below input flags **(flag to capitalize)** in xml are not working -

`InputType="textCapSentences"`

`InputType="textCapWords"`

`InputType="textCapCharacters"`

are not working.

I also tried to set input type programmatically with given code -

`edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)`

but that cause even a big problem and make keyboard invisible(translucent). I checked status that keyboard is present but not rendered properly, just a blank white space.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try in xml layout add property:

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```